# best approach to store (int xIndex, int yIndex, View view, String cellName)

Tags: java, android, arrays, hashmap

I'm working on small Android library and for specific reason I need to store a structure like this
(

- int xIndex - a x index of a view in a table-like structure
- int yIndex - a y index of a view in a table-like structure
- View view - the view itself
- String cellName - this is a name of a cell with coordinates x, y in a table-like structure

so I can later address the stored View either by (xIndex,yIndex) or by it's cellName in the following manner:

```
View view = manager.getCell(xIndex, yIndex);
//or 
View view = manager.getByName(cellName);
```

I actually want this implementation to be as simple as possible, so any ideas on what kind of Map or something similar I can use to be able to address objects there either by a pair of integers or by a String? I don't want to create an intermediate class like following

`CellDefinition(int x, int y, String cellName)`

so later it can be done like this Map<CellDefinition, View> rather I would need something like
`Object<Integer[2], String, View>`

so I can later address it by
`new[]{x,y}` or by String `"cellName"`
and retrieve the View object by these indexes.

Any ideas are welcome

Comment: using an intermediate class here is going to give you a lot more flexibility in future. if you were to add or remove fields in future, it would be a lot less painful

Comment: Why wouldn't you want to make a class that represents a literal software entity? That's what they're there for

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could do something like `List<Map<String, Object>>` where the list is a collection of Maps that take place of a new class objects. For example, your key value pairs might looks like `{ "Name" : "CellName", "x" : 1, "y" : 2, "View" : viewObj}`

From there, you could use a stream and the resulting map to select your view:

```
List<HashMap<String, Object> list = ...

//By name
HashMap<String, Object> selectedMap = list.stream()
        .filter(m -> m.get("Name").equals("SomeName"))
        .findFirst()
        .orElse(null);

//Or by point
HashMap<String, Object> selectedMap = list.stream()
        .filter(m -> m.get("x") == 1 && m.get("y") == 2)
        .findFirst()
        .orElse(null);

View view = (View) selectedMapBy.get("View");
```

At that point though, it may be easier to do something like `List<CustomClass>` instead so that you don't have to deal with keys and 'Object' types:

```
List<CellDefinition> list = ...
CellDefinition cell = list.stream()
    .filter(c -> c.getName().equals("SomeName"))
    .findFirst()
    .orElse(null);

View view = cell.getView();
```